# How to check if a string is doesn't equal all of these?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

Trying to rewrite this using LINQ:

```
if (mode != "A" && mode != "B" && mode != "C" && mode != "D" && mode != "E" && mode != "F" && mode != "G")
{
   continue;
}
```

What would be the most clear and concise way to refactor this? I could have sworn I'd seen a post like this before but I cannot find it at the moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.contains.aspx) method from `IList<T>`:

```
IList<string> modes = new[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};
if (!modes.Contains(mode))...
```

Comment: Contains is one of the more useful linq extension methods

Comment: @Adrian This particular `Contains(...)` is not even LINQ (the one from LINQ is more versatile).

Comment: Is your first line any different from: `string[] modes = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };` when used with the `Contains` method on the following line?

Comment: @RyanPeschel Yes: if your replace `IList<string>` with `var` or the equivalent `string[]`, the program would not compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Compiled just fine for me.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Interesting! Perhaps that's a mono-specific bug (i tried it on ideone).

Answer (score 2):

Write an extension method for the string class

```
public static bool In(this string s, params string[] values)
{
    return values.Any(x => x.Equals(s));
}
```

call it in this way

```
if (!mode.In("A", "B", "C", "D","E","F", "G")
{
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var modes = new[] { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};

if (modes.All(a => mode != a)) 
    continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension method all the time

```
public static bool IsIn(this string source, params string[] parms)
{
    return parms.Contains(source);
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
if (!mode.IsIn("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))
{
    continue;
}
```

The next step, if you use it much, is

```
public static bool IsNotIn(this string source, params string[] parms)
{
    return !IsIn(source, params);
}
```

and you get the slightly more readable

```
if (mode.IsNotIn("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))
{
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "ABCDEFG";
bool res = s.Any(item => { return (int)item > 64 && (int)item < 72; });
```

Comment: Hah I was afraid someone was going to post something like this. The string values aren't actually simple like the alphabet, just used to make the question simpler.